# Angular 5 log interceptor throwed error but calling function cannot read back the error

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

interceptor code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// import { tap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class LogInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log(`HTTP: ${req.urlWithParams}`);

        return next.handle(req)
            .catch((err, caught) => {
                console.log(err);
                if (err.error instanceof Error) {
                    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
                    console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
                } else {
                    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
                    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
                    console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error.message}`);
                }
                return Observable.throw(err);
            })
            .do(event => {
                console.log(event);
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log(event.body);
                }
            });
    }

}
```

Interceptor is working but the error cannot be read by the calling function and it is always null.

calling function

```
this.http.post<Asset>(`whatever.php`, {}).subscribe(
  _data => console.log(data), 
  _err => console.log(_err) // <- this _err is always NULL 
);
```

If the catch code is removed in the interceptor, the error is back. I want the interceptor to do the generic handling but also allows the calling function to handle the error if needed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
return next.handle(req).do(
      (event: HttpEvent < any > ) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log('--> event: ', event);
          console.log('--> status: ', event.status);
          this._spinnerService.requestEnded();
        }
      },
      (err: any) => { <-- The error is caught here. You didn't define any Error callback, hence it's null during your subscription.
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          console.log('--> error: ', err);
          console.log('--> errorStatus: ', err.status);
          this._spinnerService.requestEnded();
        }
      }
    );
```

Check the comment in my answer

Comment: I did return the observable.throw in my original code. Would you share how should the correct code be? Thx!

Comment: do operator is almost like subscribe operator which returns 3 callbacks: Success, Error, and Complete callbacks. The correct way to implement the Interceptor is: .do(success => {}, error? => {}, completed => {}). If you want the Calling function to catch the error from the interceptor, you have to pass the Error callback in the do operator. You never get to log the error in your calling function because the error is caught and throw before the Request actually reaches out to the server, which means the data is also null/undefined. If you get the data, it means no error and do operator executes